# Extruding rounded shape from face instead of angular

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I am currently following the famous donut tutorial while learning not only 3D modelling but Blender as well.  I am currently on this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBtDix7xGOg&t=172s and stuck on the timestamp of 2:52.

When trying to extrude my extrusion comes out angular and extruding the entire face as such

My extrusion
[image: my extrusion]

Vs

Tutorial extrusion
[image: tutorial extrusion]

Can anyone point me in the right direction to getting the rounded/more organic extrusion?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have to ask that: are you paying close attention to the tutorial? Andrew's extrusion comes out "angular" and "the entire face as such" as well. He then says he hits _R_ to rotate the face, then he's switching to vertex mode and grabs certain vertices to move them where he wants them.

Comment: Maybe you should use the shade smooth option? Go to object mode select the object RMB--> shade smooth.

Comment: have you given a Subdivision Surface modifier to your object?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I misunderstood the question - I thought you were talking of the direction of the extrusion and the size of the face. But that makes me repeat my question: did you pay attention to the tutorial? Andrew uses a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier on the cup.